# NuGet Dependency Strategy

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I am splitting many of my application models and interfaces into its own nuGet package.

The question is: Is there any good practice recommended strategy when creating nuGet packages regarding the definition of dependencies?

Sometimes a `package A` depends on a `package B`. If I don't declare a specific `package B` version on my `package A`'s nuspec, when I later on import `package A` nuGet package in any solution, it may fail at runtime because the the subdependency was not available.

Sometimes the dependency tree goes even deeper. But If I explicitly add dependencies onto each nuspec file, then I could find version conflicts later on.

The question is: What's the recommended strategy to deal with these things if everything is under my control? Should I only specify dependencies when the dependency is something "not obvious" for the project (e.g: a third party library that the project importing a nuGet wrapper needs at runtime but doesn't use directly)? Should I do it always and later on deal with version conflicts in a different way? Any good source of information regarding this would be much appreciated as I found several examples but not a recommendation of a certain way to do things.

**ANNEXED**:
The way I create nuGet packages is by including a nuspec file which I edit manually. For example if I have the following solution structure:

```
ToolBelt.CityContracts.sln
-ToolBelt.CityContracts.NuGet
--ToolBelt.CityContracts.NuGet.nuspec
-ToolBelt.CityContractsOne
-ToolBelt.CityContractsTwo
```

In `ToolBelt.CityContractsOne` and `ToolBelt.CityContractsTwo` I have my c# source files. And From `ToolBelt.CityContracts.NuGet` project I add a reference to `ToolBelt.CityContractsOne` and `ToolBelt.CityContractsTwo` to make sure that the nuspec "knows" where the source files are.

Then the nuspec looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ToolBelt.CityContracts</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>iberodev</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Shared Contracts</description>
    <dependencies>
      <!--here sub-dependencies that I want to drag across-->
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin/*/netstandard2.0/ToolBelt.CityContractsOne.dll" target="lib/netstandard2.0" />
    <file src="bin/*/netstandard2.0/ToolBelt.CityContractsOne.pdb" target="lib/netstandard2.0" />
    <file src="bin/*/netstandard2.0/ToolBelt.CityContractsTwo.dll" target="lib/netstandard2.0" />
    <file src="bin/*/netstandard2.0/ToolBelt.CityContractsTwo.pdb" target="lib/netstandard2.0" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Everything pretty standard until here.

Then I use nuget command tool to generate the nuget package inside a folder called `nupkgs` with the command:

```
nuget pack ToolBelt.CityContracts.NuGet.nuspec -Version $VERSION -OutputDirectory nupkgs -Prop Configuration=Release -NoDefaultExcludes -Verbosity detailed
```

**UPDATE 1:**
For now my strategy is the following.

1. If the `package A` exposes classes/interfaces in its public API that are part of a `package B`, then the `package A` does not add a dependency to `package B` in its nuspec. Therefore the project that adds `package A` must also explicitly add `package B`
2. If the `package A` does not expose classes/interfaces in its public API that are part of a `package B` but it uses them internally, then the `package A` must add a dependency to `package B` in its nuspec, so that the project that adds `package A` will also have `package B` installed automatically and avoid the runtime exception risk.

The idea is: if the code compiles, it should run without runtime exceptions due to inexisting dependencies.

This makes sense to me, but I cannot find any reliable source to confirm that this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're targeting netstandard2.0, an easier way to create the package is to use [dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x), rather than creating a nuspec yourself and using `nuget pack`. `dotnet pack` or `msbuild /t:pack` will pull metadata from the csproj and it automatically adds any PackageReference as a dependency to your package. if you have a build-time dependency that you don't want users of your package to get, you can use [PrivateAssets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets).

It is best practise to add all your runtime dependencies as dependencies to your package, so that anyone who references only your package, their program will not crash at runtime due to missing dlls. NuGet restore automatically handles selecting versions of dependencies when different packages request different versions, so it's something you generally shouldn't spend too much time worrying about, although sticking to Semantic Versioning helps.

On a side note, my personal opinion is that fewer packages are better. There are absolutely great reasons why an implementation of an interface may be in a different assembly/package to the definition of the interface. But unless you can justify it with a good reason, I would suggest to keep the interface and implementation in the same assembly/package. One codebase I worked on in the past had code in multiple packages across multiple repositories because the team thought some of the generic code might be useful to other projects. But bug fixing meant you have to create a new version of the dependency, then update the reference in the deployed application, and debugging of the dependency was difficult. This slowed down development significantly when we had to work on that dependency package, and in the end nothing else used it, so there was really no benefit to splitting it.

Comment: Interesting about `dotnet pack`, but what happens with solutions with several packages? I can see you can pass only a project to the `dotnet pack`. What if there's another isolated project you want to pack together?

Comment: If you have a sln file, it will try to pack every project in the solution. You have MSBuild properties to prevent packing (from memory IsPackable) so you can avoid packing certain projects if you really don't want them to be packaged. Alternatively, there's also a MSBuild property GeneratePackageOnBuild so the nupkg will be created automatically on build. No need to run pack separately.

Comment: I had a read at `dotnet pack` documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x and it seems the only argument allowed is the project to be packed. There's no option to specify a solution. Do you have an example/link where a multi-project solution is packed using `dotnet pack` and a nuGet Id is customized? (I'm doing that by defining nuspec myself)

Comment: Use [`<PackageId>` in your csproj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#packageid). It takes seconds to try running `dotnet pack` on a sln file to see if it works, even if the docs don't claim it can. I'll create an issue on the docs so hopefully the update it. Alternatively, you can set the [`<GeneratePackageOnBuild> property in your csrpoj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-the-dotnet-cli#automatically-generate-package-on-build) and you won't need to run pack as a separate step.